# Differentiation/Integration continuous function (metric spaces)

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have the following two questions:

> Is differentiation, $f(x) \mapsto f'(x)$ a continuous function from
>   $C^1[a,b] \longrightarrow C[a,b]$
>
> and
>
> Is integration, $f(x) \mapsto \int_a^x f(t) \ dt$, a continuous
>   function from $C[a,b] \longrightarrow C[a,b]$

$C[a,b]$ denotes the space of continuous real-valued functions on $[a,b]$ with the sup metric and $C^1[a,b]$ denotes the space of continuously differentiable functions on $[a,b]$

So far, I've attempted the first one and I'm trying to use the theorem that a map is continuous if and only if the inverse map applied to some set is closed in $f(x)$ whenever the set is closed in $f'(x)$ but haven't been able to get anywhere (or think of a counterexample)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specifiy a norm on these spaces to discuss continuity.  Usually, one gives $\mathcal{C}[a,b]$ the sup-norm.  In this case, integration is continuous, since if we define $$T(f)(x) = \int_0^x f(t)\,dt, \qquad t\in[a,b]$$
we have
$$|T(f)(x)| \le \left| \int_0^x f(t)\, dt\right| \le \int_0^x |f(t)|  dt 
\le \|f\|(b - a),$$
where the norm denotes the uniform norm.  This map $T: \mathcal{C}[a,b]\to
\mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

If you make the $\mathcal{C}^1$ norm $f\mapsto \|f\| + \|f'\|$, then differentiation is continuous in that norm.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I forgot to include it. It does specify the sup-metric/norm for $C[a,b]$ but mentions nothing for $C^1[a,b]$

Answer (score 0):

Consider a function f= epsilon * exp (-x^2/epsilon^2) on the domain [-a,a] and epsilon in neighbourhood of 0.

Then supremum /f/ = epsilon

Differentiate f. f' = -2x/ epsilon  * exp (-x^2/epsilon^2)

supremum /f'/ = 1/ epsilon.

As epsilon   tends to 0, supremum /f'/  tends to infinity.

Thus no,  differentiation is not cts function from C' into C.

Comment: Abbreviations tend to be confusing, especially for the users who don't speak English as their first language. Please use "neighborhood" instead of "nhd," "continuous" instead of "cts," etc. In particular, do *not* use "inf" as a substitute for "infinity," especially not in a sentence that also contains "sup"!